# Using Bootstrap Glyphicon inside 'input' box distorting other elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have a search box in which I am displaying a Bootstrap glyphicon on the right.  Next to my search box, I have a simple

tag displaying the number of search results.  Everything is properly lined up before I add the glyphicon.  I cannot for the life of me figure out why adding the glyphicon is throwing off the next element.  This is probably the simplest thing I have ever posted to SO but the one that has driven me the craziest thus far.

My HTML:

```
<div class="main-wrap">
            <h1>Search Results for "undergraduate"</h1>
            <div class="search-holder">
                <div class="right-inner-addon">
                    <input type="search" class="results"></input>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                    <p>248 Results</p>
                </div><!--end right-inner-addon-->
            </div><!--end search-holder-->
        </div><!--end main-wrap-->
```

And my CSS:

```
.template-f {
  padding: 100px 0px;
}

.template-f .search-holder {
  width: 630px;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 95%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.template-f .search-holder .right-inner-addon {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
}

.template-f .search-holder .right-inner-addon .search-crate {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.template-f .search-holder .right-inner-addon p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.template-f .search-holder .right-inner-addon i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #003366;
}
```

Would love some help here...

Comment: Please show CSS, not server-side code. It facilitates the use of it in demos.

Comment: Here's a start. Does it demonstrate the problem accurately? http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/a8uabqa5/

Comment: Updated to CSS, and yes your fiddle shows my exact problem

Comment: You should be using the bootstrap syntax for adding in a glyph icon with a form element.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you want it to look like? Do you want the 248 results beside it the search input?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Joe.  I would like the '248 results' to be outside of the search box, but inline. I thought I was using the bootstrap syntax